# How to maintain TD width in 100% width table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a 100% width table that fits the entire html body. Each `<td>` has a fixed width, which in sum exceeds the body width.

The HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>

etc... etc...

            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>last one in the line</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Simple CSS to demonstrate:

```
table td {
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Here is an example JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/H55Se/)

The problem is that instead of overflowing the body and showing a horizontal scrollbar, the table reduces each `<td>`'s width to fit the document.

How can I force the width and show a scrollbar?

Comment: Yuck! There's tables.

Answer (score 4):

Use `min-width` instead to force the cell to always keep the width.

```
table td {
    min-width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H55Se/3/

Comment: Brilliant! Can't believe I didn't try it... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use use min-width, as below

```
table td {min-width: 100px; border: solid 1px black;white-space: nowrap;}
```